# how to exactly transfer checked rows from gridview1 to gridview2 (both are in the same page)

Tags: asp.net, gridview

currently this method is displaying in a gridview2 just the first column of the rows checked in gridview1 checkboxes but i need to display all of the columns exactly as gridview1, so how do i do it?

```
protected void Button1_Click2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
List<string> lista = new List<string>();

    for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            CheckBox chbox = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("chk") as CheckBox;
            if (chbox.Checked == true)
        {
            lista.Add("'" + GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text + "'");
        }   
        }   

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    GridView2.DataSource = lista;
    GridView2.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

code to of your button will be below

```
protected void Button1_Click2(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<CopyGrid> lista = new List<CopyGrid>();

            for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                CheckBox chbox = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("chk") as CheckBox;
                if (chbox.Checked == true)
                {
                    CopyGrid content = new CopyGrid();
                    content.Name = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text;
                    content.Email = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text;
                    content.City = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text;
                    content.PostCode = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Text;
                    lista.Add(content);
                }
            }

            //     DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            GridView2.DataSource = lista;
            GridView2.DataBind();
        }
```

also create one class that will store details of gridview1

```
public class CopyGrid
    {
        public string Name;
        public string Email;
        public string City;
        public string PostCode;

    }
```

This is just sample code you have to implement your own code.

Comment: that didn't solved the problem, it keeps displaying only the first column of checked rows in gridview1, i think what i need to do is store values in a bidimensional array, iterate through each row of gridview1 checking if it's checked and then storing values horizontally if it is
maybe with a 'for loop' inside the 'if'?

Comment: but your code is worked at my end just I have change thing that I have mentioned and GridView2 is like <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GridView2" ></asp:GridView>

Comment: My gridview1 has multiple columns and with that method in my code is listing the checked rows but it is only displaying the first column

Comment: but your code is to get only first columns value in your list so for that in GridView2 it only display first column values. You have to create list with all fields and bind that to GridView2. Generate one class with the properties of columns that you want to display in GridView2

Comment: That"s what i'm asking for because i don't know how

Comment: let me give you example

Comment: thank you but it didn't work an exception ocurred in this line GridView2.DataBind();System.InvalidOperationException:The data source for GridView with id 'TestGrid' did not have any properties
or attributes from which to generate columns.  Ensure that your data source has content.

how about using a bidimensional array to store the values? it just seems too much complication to create a class just to transfer values from one object to another

Comment: check your gridview2 bound columns name and datafield and set same name to your class which you have used as a list to store checked values from GridView1. Another thing that you can try is to convert List to DataTable and pass to GridView2